# What was that early TV or cinema commercial which was (maybe) the first to feature a shower/somebody showering?

Tags: united-states, 1930s, 1920s, advertising, commercial

I don't remember when I saw or heard this, where or in what form, but I either listened to the radio maybe 10-15 years ago, or watched it on TV around the same time. I *think* they were talking either about early forms of advertising, or shampoo ads, or something else entirely. The only memories I have left of this "occurrence" are the following:

1. It was about a shower, or shampoo, soap, shower hats or something related to that.
2. The year was somewhere in 1910-1935, most likely ~1925 or ~1930.
3. I remember a black-and-white shower scene (not showing anything nude, of course), featuring a smiling young lady with short black hair, but I'm unsure if I really saw this with my eyes or just imagined it.
4. I *think* it featured a soothing/relaxing/dreamy soundtrack of some sort, sounding very "watery" or "flowing".
5. It was in English language and I'm 99% sure that it was in/from the USA.

I remember this short sequence and the feeling it evoked in me. For some reason, I found it really fascinating to see this early video commercial, and I wish I could again see it and read more about it.

Sorry for being so vague, but the things I want to re-discover the most are always the foggiest memories!

In this case, there's a pretty big chance that somebody will instantly know what I'm talking about. My guess is that it was something along the lines of the first shampoo/shower TV or cinema commercial ever. Probably cinema since TV had barely been invented back then...

Do you know what I'm talking about?

Comment: You might be better off having this migrated to [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SteveBird They don't accept identification questions, this would be off-topic there.

Comment: According to [this](https://medium.com/knowledge-stew/the-worlds-first-television-commercial-4f0b73f27b07) the first TV commercial wasn't broadcast in th US until 1941, and it was a watch commercial.

Comment: [Here is an early advertisement for soap from 1922](https://youtu.be/4e5ZDfKokQ8).

Comment: [In 1930](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/what-was-the-first-broadcast-television-programme/43913#43913), Charles Francis Jenkins was fined for breaching regulations when he broadcast [first TV commercial](http://www.mztv.com/timeline/first-tv-commercial/).